# SQL OrderBy, how to use with keyword AS

Tags: sql

I have a query that selects specific items as a keyword as shown below.

```
SELECT system_title as Request,
    Description.Words as Changes,
    Projects.ProjectNodeName as ProjectName,
    COALESCE(Engineer.Name + ' <' + UPPER(Engineer.Domain + '\' + Engineer.Alias) + '>', 'N/A')  as 
    Engineer
```

I want to use `ORDER BY Request` to order each selected item basted off of `Request`
Where would I put the `ORDER BY Request` in here to make the syntax work and do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Request` is not in any of the tables, then you should be able to do:

```
SELECT system_title as Request,
    Description.Words as Changes,
    Projects.ProjectNodeName as ProjectName,
    COALESCE(Engineer.Name + ' <' + UPPER(Engineer.Domain + '\' + Engineer.Alias) + '>', 'N/A')  as 
    Engineer
FROM . . .
ORDER BY Request;
```

The standard specifies -- and I think all databases support -- columns aliases in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what database system you are using.  Some allow you to reference column aliases directly in the same query block, so you could simply add `ORDER BY Request` on the end of your query.  I'm guessing that since you're asking the question, you're using a system that doesn't allow this.  (Oracle, for example, does not.)

You can achieve this by nesting your query in another one, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT system_title AS Request,
  ...
)
ORDER BY Request
```

Or a slightly different approach is to use a CTE like this:

```
WITH unsorted_data AS (
  SELECT system_title AS Request,
  ...
)
SELECT * FROM unsorted_data
ORDER BY Request
```

Comment: I put the ORDER BY after the WHERE and it worked, thanks! (also referenced this link  https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/order_by.php ) 

I am still a new person to using SQL and forgot about different databases